# Showing all data in Redis table

Tags: redis

I'm not familiar with Redis at all (more familiar with mySQL), so please pardon me if my question isn't phrased correctly.

I have a Redis database, with each entry/record containing 5 fields. I want to see all the 5 fields values of each record, but so far, most of the commands I found online focused on "keys", which only display the values of 1 of the 5 fields.

Basically, what I want to check is if 2 records with (one) same field value will both be inserted into the database, or if only one will get inserted. If the same field value happens to be the "key", then I guess only one will be inserted? Will the first inserted record be kept, or the last inserted record?

Comment: Hi what command you used to write data ? Redis has several types for saving data.

Comment: The command used (by the person who wrote the code) is `SET field1 field2;field3;field4;field5`. I noticed that `field1` and `field2` is separated by a space, but the other 4 fields are separated by ; -- does this mean something?

Comment: Your question is too abstract to answer. Elaborate your question with data type (Set, Sorted Set, Hash Map etc) you use and a simple example with what you want and how you are trying to achieve the same.

Comment: The command used was `SET`. I actually just want to find out the command for listing all entries in the table, i.e. show values for all 5 fields of each record, rather than just showing the "keys", which is only 1 of the 5 fields.

Comment: when you write `SET field1 field2;field3;field4` that means you add one record where key name `field1` and value `field2;field3;field4` so you can write `GET field1` and get value of this key

Comment: There is some serious problem in the way you understand redis. Give these links a try, and then come back with your questions.  

http://try.redis.io/   

http://redis.io/commands